Can anyone explain why new tags cannot be created from the mobile site?
Can anyone explain why new tags cannot be created from the mobile site?
I don't see any reason why it is so, and so I hope our moderators could do something to remove this restriction.

Well, I guess it's something related to every Stack sites, isn't it?

From an SE dev's comment on this MSO answer:

It's very rare that a new tag is intentionally and correctly created, and mobile device auto correct and difficulty typing makes it even more likely that tags are accidentally created. We just disallowed it altogether accordingly.

